# get list of students on the bais Status value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have to retrieve the list of students on the basis of value of `Status` field in Index view.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<School> schools = schoolRepo.Collection().ToList();
            return View(schools);
        }
```

Here all the students are retrieved irrespective of `Status` value. But I want to show only those students whose Status value `!=0`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use lambda expression to filter your results:

```
List<School> schools = schoolRepo.Where(c => c.Status != 0).ToList();
```